# PHP: Upgrade MD5 hash app to bycript. Is this secure?

Tags: php, hash

Sorry is this is asked somewhere else, but i didn't found it. 
The problem is, im triying to upgrade my legacy PHP app to a more secure password hash. Currently i have MD5, but i want to use bycript with the new password_hash() function. I thought of a way, but i dont know if is really secure. This is a simplified code:

```
if (password_verify($input_password, $user->password hash) === false) {
    if (md5($input_password) === $user->password_hash) {
        user->password_hash = password_hash(
            $input_password,
            $currentHashAlgoritm,
            $currentHashOptions
        );
        $user->save;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Invalid Password');
    }
}
//Save login status to session
```

Basically, what im trying to do is rehash the password if the initial check is bad, but the MD5 check is good. BUT, what happens if someone puts a bad password and:

```
md5($bad_password) == $user->password_hash (hashed by bycript)
```

Is a very slim possibility for an user to enter with a bad password.

Is this the only way or is other better way to to that? Thanks to all. And sorry for the bad english.

Comment: just a thought: How about adding some indicator if a stored hash is already bcrypt hashed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's fine, as PHP's [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) includes coding in its returned hash that identify the algorithm, cost and salt, and it uses characters that can never be in an md5 hash, which is purely hex.

Therefore `md5($bad_password)` can never be identical to a result from `password_hash` (take a look at the values; the bcrypt from `password_hash` will start "$2y$", and neither "$" nor "y" can ever be in an md5 hash. The "$2y$" indicates that the password is a bcrypt hash in [modular crypt format](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html).)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that.